# Custom rule to move work item to different area path

Tags: kanban

Is it possible to create a custom rule or some other method to automatically move a work item from the DONE state/column to an Area called "Archive" and change the iteration to one of our archive iterations based on a rule? Ultimately we want an automated process to archive work items in the DONE column after a specific date. For example, I set up an Archive area and various archive iterations based on the quarter of the fiscal year. We have a requirement to maintain this documentation for x years and don't want to see it all in the DONE column for years to come.

Comment: What Kanban tool are you using?

Comment: Azure DecOPS Kanban board.